# How create Date Object with values in java

Tags: java, date

I need a date object for date 2014-02-11. 
I can't directly create it like this,

```
Date myDate = new Date(2014, 02, 11);
```

So I'm doing like follows,

```
Calendar myCalendar = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 11);
Date myDate = myCalendar.getTime();
```

Is there any easy way to create date object in java?

Comment: What's not easy in your approach ?

Comment: "Is there any easy way". What makes you think that is not as easy as it can be? Times and dates are much more complicated than you might think. There are multiple calendars and multiple time-zones.

Comment: One line like, `Date myDate = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 11).getTime();`?

Comment: Beware of using a leading zero in an integer literal as seen in this Question, `02`. In Java, that means an [octal (base-8) number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) rather than a decimal (base-10) number.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the Date constructor takes year - 1900 (and month is zero based), so new Date(114, 01, 11) is more appropriate.

Answer (score 158):

Gotcha: passing 2 as month may give you unexpected result: in Calendar API, month is zero-based.  2 actually means March.

I don't know what is an "easy" way that you are looking for as I feel that using Calendar is already easy enough.

Remember to use correct constants for month:

```
 Date date = new GregorianCalendar(2014, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 11).getTime();
```

---

Another way is to make use of DateFormat, which I usually have a util like this:

```
 public static Date parseDate(String date) {
     try {
         return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         return null;
     }
  }
```

so that I can simply write

```
Date myDate = parseDate("2014-02-14");
```

---

Yet another alternative I prefer: Don't use Java Date/Calendar anymore.  Switch to JODA Time or Java Time (aka JSR310, available in JDK 8+).  You can use `LocalDate` to represent a date, which can be easily created by

```
LocalDate myDate =LocalDate.parse("2014-02-14");
// or
LocalDate myDate2 = new LocalDate(2014, 2, 14);
// or, in JDK 8+ Time
LocalDate myDate3 = LocalDate.of(2014, 2, 14);
```

Comment: `.toTime()` doesn't exist. It should be `.getTime()` (see [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()))

Comment: Sorry a typo. Though I think OP already knows the correct method to call :P

Comment: Pretty sure you are right. But for those (like me) who have to look it up every time it is needed it is annoying. Thanks for fixing :)

Comment: `return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date) `
should be
`return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date)`

Comment: Good catch. Dunno why I made such mistake. Fixing it

Answer (score 73):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2014 , 2 , 11 )
```

If you insist on using the terrible old `java.util.Date` class, convert from the modern *java.time* classes.

```
java.util.Date                        // Terrible old legacy class, avoid using. Represents a moment in UTC. 
.from(                                // New conversion method added to old classes for converting between legacy classes and modern classes.
    LocalDate                         // Represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    .of( 2014 , 2 , 11 )              // Specify year-month-day. Notice sane counting, unlike legacy classes: 2014 means year 2014, 1-12 for Jan-Dec.
    .atStartOfDay(                    // Let java.time determine first moment of the day. May *not* start at 00:00:00 because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).
        ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )   // Specify time zone as `Continent/Region`, never the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones like `PST`, `EST`, or `IST`. 
    )                                 // Returns a `ZonedDateTime`.
    .toInstant()                      // Adjust from zone to UTC. Returns a `Instant` object, always in UTC by definition.
)                                     // Returns a legacy `java.util.Date` object. Beware of possible data-loss as any microseconds or nanoseconds in the `Instant` are truncated to milliseconds in this `Date` object.
```

## Details

If you want "easy", you should be using the new [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8 rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java.

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes.

### Date-only

[image]

A [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class is offered by java.time to represent a date-only value without any time-of-day or time zone. You do need a time zone to determine a date, as a new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal for example. The [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) class is for time zones.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Singapore" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId );
```

Dump to console:

```
System.out.println ( "today: " + today + " in zone: " + zoneId );
```

> today: 2015-11-26 in zone: Asia/Singapore

Or use a factory method to specify the year, month, day.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2014 , Month.FEBRUARY , 11 );
```

> localDate: 2014-02-11

Or pass a month number 1-12 rather than a `DayOfWeek` enum object.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2014 , 2 , 11 );
```

### Time zone

[image]

A `LocalDate` has no real meaning until you adjust it into a time zone. In java.time, we apply a time zone to generate a `ZonedDateTime` object. That also means a time-of-day, but what time? Usually makes sense to go with first moment of the day. You might think that means the time `00:00:00.000`, but not always true because of Daylight Saving Time (DST) and perhaps other anomalies. Instead of assuming that time, we ask java.time to determine the first moment of the day by calling [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Singapore" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = localDate.atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

> zdt: 2014-02-11T00:00+08:00[Asia/Singapore]

### UTC

[image]

For back-end work (business logic, database, data storage & exchange) we usually use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. In java.time, the [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in UTC. An Instant object can be extracted from a ZonedDateTime by calling [`toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

> instant: 2014-02-10T16:00:00Z

### Convert

You should avoid using `java.util.Date` class entirely. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert back-and-forth. Look to new conversion methods added to the old classes.

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.from( instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = d.toInstant() ;
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

UPDATE: The *Joda-Time* library is now in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the *java.time* classes. I am leaving this section in place for history.

## Joda-Time

For one thing, Joda-Time uses sensible numbering so February is `2` not `1`. Another thing, a Joda-Time DateTime truly knows its assigned time zone unlike a java.util.Date which seems to have time zone but does not.

And don't forget the time zone. Otherwise you'll be getting the JVM’s default.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Singapore" );
DateTime dateTimeSingapore = new DateTime( 2014, 2, 11, 0, 0, timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeSingapore.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

java.util.Locale locale = new java.util.Locale( "ms", "SG" ); // Language: Bahasa Melayu (?). Country: Singapore.
String output = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( locale ).print( dateTimeSingapore );
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeSingapore: " + dateTimeSingapore );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeSingapore: 2014-02-11T00:00:00.000+08:00
dateTimeUtc: 2014-02-10T16:00:00.000Z
output: Selasa, 2014 Februari 11 00:00:00 SGT
```

### Conversion

If you need to convert to a java.util.Date for use with other classes…

```
java.util.Date date = dateTimeSingapore.toDate();
```

Comment: Just one comment.  Practice of prefixing zeros in the fields like `new DateTime( 2014, 02, 11, 0, 0, timeZone );` is probably not preferrable.  Though it works in this case, but, it won't compile for August and September if you are passing `08` and `09` as prefixing an int literal with 0 means octal presentation.  It will even give you unexpected values for years before `1000`, e.g. `new DateTime( 0100, 02, 01, 0, 0, timeZone );` that one may expect it to be 100AD but actually it is 64AD

Comment: @AdrianShum Yikes! I never knew an innocent little typo like a leading zero on an integer literal could have such a nasty side-effect. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: "If you insist on using the terrible old java.util.Date class". Many providers do not offer tomcat servers that run on Java beyond JDK7, so, while I would loove to use the newer stuff, some are stuck at the old shit because of others.....

Comment: @KimvdLinde Reread my Answer more carefully. Look at the bullets. Find the words “Java SE 6 and Java SE 7”.

Answer (score 22):

I think the best way would be using a `SimpleDateFormat` object.

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateString = "2014-02-11";
Date dateObject = sdf.parse(dateString); // Handle the ParseException here
```

Comment: Y.. And be sure to never use YYYY - use yyyy - especially if doing this in reverse with format instead of parse. You get some odd results!!! See here: https://code.sololearn.com/c0EYUAOc92uQ/#java

Comment: Just lost hours trying to fix output when I got to this comment - here is the reason why YYYY wont work... is for the week year... whatever that is  - You will get to something like 27 December and the year will be the next year. e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 21):

From Java8:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Date;

Date date = Date.from(Instant.parse("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date todayDate = new Date();
    cal.setTime(todayDate);

    // Set time fields to zero
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    todayDate = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
//format as u want

try {
    String dateStart = "June 14 2018 16:02:37";
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse(dateStart));
    //all done
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The terrible `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Suggesting their use in 2018 is poor advice.

Comment: This Answer does not address the specifics of this Question.

Comment: By “API levels” I assume you mean Android. But this is not an Android-specific Question. Furthermore, most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project. Further adapted to Android in the *ThreeTenABP* project. So, no need to ever use those awful legacy date-time classes. The *java.time* classes are radically better.

Comment: Thanks for this comment.Does this library provides function like  date difference and time differences.

Comment: Yes. Search Stack Overflow for the many existing Q & A on this topic. And see the *ThreeTen-Extra* project too (not back-ported to early Android).

Answer (score 0):

Simplest ways:

```
Date date = Date.valueOf("2000-1-1");
LocalDate localdate = LocalDate.of(2000,1,1);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2000,1,1,0,0);
```

Comment: One should avoid the first one since the `java.sql.Date` class that you are using is poorly designed and long outdated. I recommend using `LocalDate` as in the second line. My habit is `LocalDate.of(2000, Month.JANUARY, 1)`, I find it a bit clearer to read.

Comment: and that because answer contains LocalDate declaration, not only asked Date object (not deprecated, and used sometimes)...

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Solution 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<Integer,String> hm = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
        hm.put(1,"SUNDAY");
        hm.put(2,"MONDAY");
        hm.put(3,"TUESDAY");
        hm.put(4,"WEDNESDAY");
        hm.put(5,"THURSDAY");
        hm.put(6,"FRIDAY");
        hm.put(7,"SATURDAY");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String month = in.next();
        String day = in.next();
        String year = in.next();

        String format = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;
        Date date = null;
        try
        {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            date = formatter.parse(format);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        System.out.println(hm.get(dayOfWeek));
    }
}
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter can be used to format the Date according to us. and then parsing inside the Date Object. Above program shows how to get week days by giving any date.

Answer (score -6):

I think your date comes from php and is written to html (dom) or?
I have a php-function to prep all dates and timestamps. This return a formation that is be needed.

```
$timeForJS = timeop($datetimeFromDatabase['payedon'], 'js', 'local'); // save 10/12/2016 09:20 on var
```

this format can be used on js to create new Date...

```
<html>
   <span id="test" data-date="<?php echo $timeForJS; ?>"></span>
   <script>var myDate = new Date( $('#test').attr('data-date') );</script>
</html>
```

What i will say is, make your a own function to wrap, that make your life easyr.
You can us my func as sample but is included in my cms you can not 1 to 1 copy and paste :)

```
    function timeop($utcTime, $for, $tz_output = 'system')
{
    // echo "<br>Current time ( UTC ): ".$wwm->timeop('now', 'db', 'system');
    // echo "<br>Current time (USER): ".$wwm->timeop('now', 'db', 'local');
    // echo "<br>Current time (USER): ".$wwm->timeop('now', 'D d M Y H:i:s', 'local');
    // echo "<br>Current time with user lang (USER): ".$wwm->timeop('now', 'datetimes', 'local');

    // echo '<br><br>Calculator test is users timezone difference != 0! Tested with "2014-06-27 07:46:09"<br>';
    // echo "<br>Old time (USER -> UTC): ".$wwm->timeop('2014-06-27 07:46:09', 'db', 'system');
    // echo "<br>Old time (UTC -> USER): ".$wwm->timeop('2014-06-27 07:46:09', 'db', 'local');

    /** -- */
    // echo '<br><br>a Time from db if same with user time?<br>';
    // echo "<br>db-time (2019-06-27 07:46:09) time left = ".$wwm->timeleft('2019-06-27 07:46:09', 'max');
    // echo "<br>db-time (2014-06-27 07:46:09) time left = ".$wwm->timeleft('2014-06-27 07:46:09', 'max', 'txt');

    /** -- */
    // echo '<br><br>Calculator test with other formats<br>';
    // echo "<br>2014/06/27 07:46:09: ".$wwm->ntimeop('2014/06/27 07:46:09', 'db', 'system');

    switch($tz_output){
        case 'system':
            $tz = 'UTC';
            break;

        case 'local':
            $tz = $_SESSION['wwm']['sett']['tz'];
            break;

        default:
            $tz = $tz_output;
            break;
    }

    $date = new DateTime($utcTime,  new DateTimeZone($tz));

    if( $tz != 'UTC' ) // Only time converted into different time zone
    {
        // now check at first the difference in seconds
        $offset = $this->tz_offset($tz);
        if( $offset != 0 ){
            $calc = ( $offset >= 0  ) ? 'add' : 'sub';
            // $calc = ( ($_SESSION['wwm']['sett']['tzdiff'] >= 0 AND $tz_output == 'user') OR ($_SESSION['wwm']['sett']['tzdiff'] <= 0 AND $tz_output == 'local') ) ? 'sub' : 'add';
            $offset = ['math' => $calc, 'diff' => abs($offset)];
            $date->$offset['math']( new DateInterval('PT'.$offset['diff'].'S') ); // php >= 5.3 use add() or sub()
        }
    }

    // create a individual output
    switch( $for ){
        case 'js':
            $format = 'm/d/Y H:i'; // Timepicker use only this format m/d/Y H:i without seconds // Sett automatical seconds default to 00
            break;
        case 'js:s':
            $format = 'm/d/Y H:i:s'; // Timepicker use only this format m/d/Y H:i:s with Seconds
            break;
        case 'db':
            $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; // Database use only this format Y-m-d H:i:s
            break;
        case 'date':
        case 'datetime':
        case 'datetimes':
            $format = wwmSystem::$languages[$_SESSION['wwm']['sett']['isolang']][$for.'_format']; // language spezific output
            break;
        default:
            $format = $for;
            break;
    }

    $output = $date->format( $format );

    /** Replacement
     * 
     * D = day short name
     * l = day long name
     * F = month long name
     * M = month short name
     */
    $output = str_replace([
        $date->format('D'),
        $date->format('l'),
        $date->format('F'),
        $date->format('M')
    ],[
        $this->trans('date', $date->format('D')),
        $this->trans('date', $date->format('l')),
        $this->trans('date', $date->format('F')),
        $this->trans('date', $date->format('M'))
    ], $output);

    return $output; // $output->getTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: Why are you answering a >2 year old **Java** question with an answer in PHP?